# Is there a cleaner way to code this piece of code using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a table in my application and I want to implement sort features now. So I have this:

```
<div class="row dashboard__block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center text-primary mb-3">
        <strong>Prices are accurate as
          of <%= CardHelper::get_update_accuracy(Time.now - @last_update) %></strong>
      </div>
    </div>

    <% if active_cards.present? %>
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-smaller">
          <thead>
          <tr>
          <%# todo: create sort links to append parameters asc and desc %>
            <th scope="col">
              <%= link_to dashboard_active_path(params.permit(:layout, :page, :items_per_page).merge(active_title_sort: :desc)) do %>
                Item title <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
              <% end %>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
              <%= link_to dashboard_active_path(params.permit(:layout, :page, :items_per_page).merge(active_current_price_sort: :desc)) do %>
                Current Price <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
              <% end %>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
              <%= link_to dashboard_active_path(params.permit(:layout, :page, :items_per_page).merge(active_time_left_sort: :desc)) do %>
                Time Left <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
              <% end %>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">Item Link</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <% if active_cards.present? %>
            <% active_cards.each do |card| %>
              <tr>
                <th><%= card.item_title %></th>
                <th>$ <%= card.sale_price.present? ? sprintf('%.2f', card.sale_price) : "Not Available" %></th>
                <th><%= card.sale_date %></th>
                <% if card.item_id.present? %>
                  <th>
                    <%= link_to "https://www.website.com/itm/#{card.item_id}", target: '_blank' do %>
                      <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View
                    <% end %>
                  </th>
                <% else %>
                  <th>
                    Not Available
                  </th>
                <% end %>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/empty_block' %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to refactor the links on the table header which now looks like:

```
<th scope="col">
              <%= link_to dashboard_active_path(params.permit(:layout, :page, :items_per_page).merge(active_title_sort: :desc)) do %>
                Item title <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
              <% end %>
            </th>
```

So I was thinking how I could implement a helper method to return these links with the proper icons, links with the params kept and as HTML.

My start point is like this:

```
def sortable(path, column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {sort: column, direction: direction}, {class: css_class}
  end
```

That I took from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWYiAVMSHD4&t=460s

I wanted to write a cleaner code than this.

Thanks.

Comment: as a note `<th />` stands for "table header" but since you are putting the data in the body of the table `<td />` ("table data") is the more appropriate tag. Also since you seem to understand the concept of partials. I would recommend pulling your table body rows out into a partial and just using `<%= render  'active_cards', collection: active_cards %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make some helper methods for this view to clean things up a lot.

```
def link_to_dashboard(text, extra_params)
  link_params = params.permit(:layout, :page, :items_per_page).merge(extra_params)
  link_to dashboard_active_path(link_params) do
    %Q|#{text} <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>|
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like:

```
<%= link_to_dashboard('Item Title', active_title_sort: :desc) %>
```

You could also use a loop to create the `th`s.

```
<tr>
  <%
    [
      ['Item title', {active_title_sort: :desc}],
      ['Current Price', {active_current_price_sort: :desc}],
      ['Time Left', {active_time_left_sort: :desc}],
    ].each do |label, sort_params|
  %>
    <th scope="col">
      <%= link_to_dashboard(label, sort_params) %>
    </th>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

A loop like that makes it much easier to add more sort column headers. You could even specify that array in your controller and use an instance variable. That would be cleanest. Put it into a constant at the top of the controller, and set an instance variable to the constant inside the action. This would also be efficient, as you'd reuse the same hash (as long as you don't mutate it).

Comment: This looks great! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Also, I just noticed, your entire table is wrapped in `active_cards.present?`. Because of that, you don't need to do it again before iterating over the array inside of `<tbody>`. You already know that it's present, so you can just delete those two lines and tab everything left 1.

Comment: Additionally, you could extract the rows in `<tbody>` out to a partial. 

Then right inside of `<tbody>`, you'd just do `<%= render(partial: 'active_card', collection: active_cards, as: :card) %>` and move contents of the `each` into the new partial, and delete the `each` since render partial will iterate over the collection for you, calling the partial once per item in the array.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts%5Fand%5Frendering.html#rendering-collections